# What are acceptable glPolygonMode first-argument values?

Tags: opengl

The documentation for glPolygonMode only specifies the enum `GL_FRONT_AND_BACK` as an acceptable first parameter (`face`). Are there other acceptable enums, such as only the front, or only the back?

```
glPolygonMode(GLenum face, GLenum mode);
```

I know that `mode` only supports `GL_POINT`, `GL_LINE`, and `GL_FILL`, but it just seems extremely strange that the only one the documentation specifies for `face` is `GL_FRONT_AND_BACK`, but it's a requirement to use it as an argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`glPolygonMode` accepted different parameters for the `face` in legacy OpenGL contexts. If you look at the [Khronos man page for it for OpenGL 2.1](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPolygonMode.xml), it says:

> face Specifies the polygons that mode applies to. Must be GL_FRONT for
>   front-facing polygons, GL_BACK for back-facing polygons, or
>   GL_FRONT_AND_BACK for front- and back-facing polygons.

Conversely, in the [OpenGL 4 man page](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPolygonMode.xhtml), it says:

> face Specifies the polygons that mode applies to. Must be
>   GL_FRONT_AND_BACK for front- and back-facing polygons.

In the OpenGL 3.3 spec, in the section 'E2. Deprecated and Removed Features', it lists:

> Separate polygon draw mode - PolygonMode face values of FRONT and
>   BACK; polygons are always drawn in the same mode, no matter which face
>   is being rasterized.

Likely, the `face` parameter was just retained for compilation equivalence for different OpenGL context targets, even though in modern OpenGL, it can really only have one value, and is now redundant.

Comment: The compilation equivalence actually hadn't occurred to me, but the idea of it being deprecated (`GL_FRONT` and `GL_BACK`) had. It just didn't seem plausible enough to roll with.